# Better alternative for "bring something to something"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expression-choice, synonyms

Is it correct to say

> *bring some experience to some activity*,

as in

> *Our product brings new experience to everyday shopping*

(artificial example) or there is an expression, that fits better? I thought about

> *introduce ... experience to activity*

and

> *add ... experience to activity*.

Also, a grammar checker I tried (Grammarly) says, that

> *bring ... experience to activity*

is not correct, while

> *bring ... experience into activity*

is OK for it.

Comment: This reminds me of resume writing:  "Experienced programmer brings creative drive to development process".  I know that's correct.  "into" implies you're going inside it.  I think your grammar checker is full of it.

Comment: @CandiedOrange And what about the case, when the subject is not a person (as in the updated example)?

Comment: Well since we're throwing around "artificial examples":  Our paint brings the color blue **to** your wall.  Our windows open to bring fresh air **into** your home.  **Into** would only make sense when something is going inside.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Well, I think using *to* is better than *into* in my case, but my main doubts is about *bring* vs *introduce* vs *add* vs etc. Btw, by artificial I meant that *new* and *shopping* can be replaced with some other words, but *experience* and *everyday* must persist.

Comment: I know it's just an artificial example, but by "new experience(s)" do you mean "[some] excitement"?

Comment: @PapaPoule Yes, kind of.

Comment: I think "into" would work only/best if you added "your": "bring new experiences into YOUR [everyday] shopping (YOUR life/YOUR etc) but as it is, I agree that "to" would be better (and I'd pluralize "experiences" [or change it to "[some] excitement." "Add" would work well, too..."introduce," also, but it would be my least favorite.

Comment: @PapaPoule OK, and what about *bring*? Is it better, than *introduce* or *add*?

Comment: see late edit to my last comment...."Add" would work well, too..."introduce," also, but it would be my least favorite."

Comment: IMO. you're confusing senses here. 'Bring experience (into play / to bear on ...)' is the 'know-how / skill' polyseme. But 'Our product makes shopping a new experience' is the 'thing experienced' grading into 'wonderful experience' sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an alternative to ***"bring something to something"*** I suggest ***"inject"*** as in ***"inject something into something"***.

For example:

***"We need to inject some experience into our company."***

***"You should inject experience into your business."***